# Typescript types allow unwanted properties

Tags: typescript, symbols, mapped-types, typescript-class

When we use a class as a type, only keys of that class should be allowed. Anyway, when assigning `[Symbol()]`, `[String()]` or `[Number()]` as property key no error is given, allowing wrong properties to be assigned. One even more curious case is that if `[Symbol()]` is assigned to a variable before being used as a prop key, it does error as expected while the same doesn't happen if we assign `[String()]` or `[Number()]` to a variable before being used.

```js
const sym = Symbol()
const str = String('another unwanted prop')
const num = Number(1)

class A { // <-- can be class/type/interface
    a?: string
    b?: number
}

let a: A = { 
    [Symbol()]: 'anything', 
    [String('unwanted prop')]: 'anything', 
    [Number(0)]: 'anything', 
    [str]: 'anything',
    [num]: 'anything',
    [sym]: 'anything' // <-- why does this error while [Symbol()], [String()] and [Number()] don't?
//  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCeBbGBeGBlJAjEAbAFAJQBQoks0ATqhlJQJZgDm+A5AIZghQAWAptQCuYAO6cofACYwADpRAzWJMtBhhByNADkNWAfgCMJUrnYQIMAIIwA3sRgOY7APwAuOHUZN7jrG7W6AsQAvsTEuHyw7O7WaDYwPg4A2piIOASEALruHGDwvF6sADQJjjApnsxswmJgEtJyCkrZMLn5PIUlieU6afoADFk5nO2dpY5JVC1tBczF3UnqiNMjs0zzZZNIK3lrrDAA9AcwADwAtGcwIjzwMJIgfBYFFgLy1Nf0EeWp6USZJRUGFUsk4wNIkr09JQ-ncHhAwKwoM4QmEVHg+AA6XAgFjsQhAA)

This doesn't looks like expected behaviour to me and I find it a bit confusing.

Is this an issue or the desired behaviour?
Am I missing something?

Comment: Same behavior if it's just `A` instead of `Props<A>`... You might want to simplify the example further.

Comment: This is because `str`, `num`, and `Symbol()` are dynamic; TypeScript doesn't know if they will resolve to valid keys. If you hover over their types, you'll see that they are of type `string`, `number`, and `symbol`, any of which could be valid keys. For example, since `str` is of type `string`, that means it could be `"a"` or `"b"`.

Comment: I have updated the question to be more specific

Comment: This is a known issue, [microsoft/TypeScript#36920](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36920), whereby computed properties that are not of unique literal types are widened to `string`, and these string index signatures are exempt from excess property warnings.  (Only `sym` is not widened) It's not necessarily a bug; they classified it as a feature request.  I believe this fully addresses your question; if you agree, let me know and I'll write up an answer.  If not, what am I missing?  (Pls mention @jcalz in your reply to notify me)

Comment: @jcalz this is just the answer i was looking for

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is (apparently) considered a missing feature of TypeScript; [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) don't generally trigger [excess property warnings](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks), unless the type of the computed property name is a single [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) (like `"abc"`) or a [`unique symbol`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#unique-symbol) type (like a named declaration `const x = Symbol()`).

See [microsoft/TypeScript#22427](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22427) which was marked as a bug but closed as "fixed" without actually being fixed, and  [microsoft/TypeScript#36920](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36920), a re-reporting of that issue which is still open but classified as a feature request instead of a bug.  So, it's a known issue, but it's more "intended" than "bug".

Excess property checking is more of a linter feature than a type safety feature.  Object types in TypeScript are open/extendible and not closed/sealed/exact; having excess properties shouldn't break an object type.  See [Use explicit properties of an object which is type annotated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72671841/2887218) for more information on why excess properties aren't actually prohibited according to the type system.

The reason why excess property warnings happen at all is to prevent people from accidentally throwing away information; if you write `const foo: {x: string} = {x: "hello", y: 123}`, the compiler warns you about `y` because you won't be able to access `y` on `foo` later on, and so you've apparently added a property that gets thrown away... and that might be a mistake.  Excess property warnings are more like a "did you mean to do this?" message and less like a "this will cause runtime errors" warning.

All this is to say that there are places where the compiler *could* issue the warning but does not.  But reports of these are generally treated like suggestions and feature requests, as the absence of the warning is an inconvenience and not a type safety hole.  For example, see [microsoft/TypeScript#20863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20863), asking for excess property warnings on non-discriminated union types.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCeBbGBeGBlJAjEAbAFAJQBQoks0ATqhlJQJZgDm+A5AIZghQAWAptQCuYAO6cofACYwADpRAzWJMtBhhByNADkNWAfgCMJUrnYQIMAIIwA3sRgOY7APwAuOHUZN7jrG7W6AsQAvsTEuHyw7O7WaHaOMADamIg4BIQAuu4cYPC8XqwAND4OyZ7MbMJiYBLScgpKWTA5eTwFxQmJOqn6AAyZ2Zyt7SVJVE0t+cxFo4nqiBNDU0wznQgLg7nLM6ERsFgxNPGOiQBE7FjAp4tbbdMwAPQPMALylCFhknzAppR8MCpYAAPdzrNIAbnCkRgAC9DnFZkCmudTo9nlwXpQ3h9iF8fuw-gDwKp4O5hPQAI6Cf5gvCQvawuFWI6zeDI9iop6Y7GhMIqPB8AB0uBALHYhCAA)

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I could find is using an interface which is not allowing symbol types:

```
type Props<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] }

interface NoSymbolInterface{
    [key: symbol]: never;
}
interface A extends NoSymbolInterface{
    a?: string
    b?: number
}

let a: Props<A> = { a: '', b: 0, [Symbol()]: 0 } //Error
```

If you must use the Class keyword, not the Interface, then something like this:

```
let a: Props<A&NoSymbolInterface> = { a: '', b: 0, [Symbol()]: 0 } //Error
```